# Using @Transactional on actors class definition with Akka 2.X.X?

Tags: java, spring, scala, akka

I used to use Spring transaction annotation over my beans.
However, actors from Akka are reluctant.
Here's my code snippet in Scala:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging { 

   def receive = {
     //......  throwing a NotInTransaction (no matter what the calling lib is)
   }
}
```

However, `@Transactional` works for all my other non-actor beans.

I added Java as tag since it is likely a similar issue with Akka for Java, I guess.

Did I miss something?

I'm pointing out I follow beforehand this technique (that I adapted in Scala) to make my actors creation aware of Spring:
http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-java-spring

**UPDATE WITH AN EXAMPLE -----------**

```
@Service("eventsListenerActor")
@Scope("prototype")
class EventsListenerActor @Autowired()(val eventRepository: EventRepository) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case RetrieveNewEvents =>
      val newEvents = eventRepository.findNewEvents(EventBatchSizeProperty)
  }

}

@Repository
class MyEventRepository extends EventRepository {

   @Transactional       //transactional annotation here
   def findNewEvents(batchSize: Int): List[Event] = {
    //................    code warning that transaction context is not present here !
  }
}
```

**Any call to the `findNewEvents` outside an actor well builds the transaction context.**

As I asked in comments below, may it be related to the actor and its way of threading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transaction tracking in application containers is based upon ThreadLocal variables, therefore it does not work with Actors. The clash is no coincidence, since having an actor take part in a larger transaction runs counter to the intention: actors shall share nothing and only communicate using messages. Two actors cannot ever be internally consistent without violating this rule.

The benefits of following this rule are plentiful: proper encapsulation, location transparency, painless distribution across CPUs or nodes, sane failure handling model.

Comment: Event if the whole actor isn't transactional (as you explained :)), I'm struggling to explain why a call from the actor to a Spring Bean annotated with `@Transactional` does not work. For example I have the bean containing a `save()` method. This method needs a transaction (constrained by the library I use). When I'm doing the exactly same call from outside an actor, it works, meaning the transaction is created. Otherwise, I got an `NotInTransactionException`. May it be related to the actor?? I don't imagine how..  Thanks :)